# Spectrogram - Calculating is wrong

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft

Ok, so basically, I am implementing the following algorithm:

1) Slice signal of size `256` with an overlap of `128`

2) Multiply each chunk with the Hanning window

3) Get DFT

4) Compute the abs value `sqrt(re*re+im*im)`

Plotting these values, as a `imshow` I get the following result:

[image]

This looks ok, it's clearly showing some difference, i.e. the spike where the signal has most amplitude shows. However, in Python I get this result:

[image]

I know that I'm doing something right, but, also doing something wrong. I just can't seem to find out where which is making me not think I have done it correctly.

Any rough ideas to where I could be going wrong here? I mean, is plotting the `abs` value the right way here or not?

[image]

Thanks

EDIT:

Result after clamping..

[image]

UPDATE:

Code:

```
for(unsigned j=0; (j < stft_temp[i].size()/2); j++)
    {
        double v = 10 * log10(stft_temp[i][j].re * stft_temp[i][j].re + stft_temp[i][j].im * stft_temp[i][j].im);

        double pixe = 1.5 * (v + 100);

        STFT[i][j] = (int) pixe; 
    }
```

Comment: Usually you would convert to log magnitude (i.e. dB) rather than linear magnitude, so it would be something like `10 * log10(re * re + im * im)`.

Comment: @PaulR Please see my updated post with the formula that you suggested. It doesn't look right. There are a lot of negative values, also, the Y axis is wrong.. Plotting the frequencies (maxBin_index * Fs / size) just gives the same result through the signal. Any suggestions? Would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: You may need to offset/scale the values to get it to look reasonable - dB values might range from say -100 to +20, and you probably want colour or intensity values from 0 to 255, so you'll need to offset and scale accordingly (and maybe clamp the max/min values too).

Comment: @PaulR Could you provide an answer, with an example / algorithm that can enable me to do that please? It all looks correct, but, as you pointed out, It might need scaling. Could adding 0.0001 or adding the minimum number with the data-set help to scale these values?

Comment: You should print out all the magnitudes and use them (the max and min's) to calculate the scaling factors suitable for your particular data set.

Comment: Not maxBin_index, but bin_index for all the bins (0..N/2), rescaled to Hz using Fs/N.  And just for labeling the Y axis, not for the points.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I realised that the `matplotlib` returned the PSD results, not the magnitude, which, is probably where I thought I was going wrong since the results do not match. Do you think, I should be implementing the PSD or just stick with magnitudes?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you might want to use a log magnitude and then scale to the required range, which would usually be 0..255. In pseudo-code:

```
mag_dB = 10 * log10(re * re + im * im);      // get log magnitude (dB)

pixel_intensity = 1.5 * (mag_dB + 100);      // offset and scale

pixel_intensity = min(pixel_intensity, 255); // clamp to 0..255
pixel_intensity = max(pixel_intensity, 0);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `pixel_intensity = min(pixel_intensity, 255)` Is this a loop?

Comment: No, it's clamping the max value to 255.

Comment: So for example in code it would just be.. `double pixe = 1.5 * (v + 100); STFT[i][j] = (int) pixe;` ?

Comment: Yes, except you want to clamp the range to whatever is valid for your image (usually 0..255), otherwise you'll get artefacts if the values wrap around.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated my post with the code I'm using. I've tried that, and, it just gives the same results as before.. Nothing changed :/

Comment: Also you might find it helpful to generate some 2D plots for some of your columns so that you can see that (a) they look like reasonable spectra and (b) you can see the magnitude of the peaks and the noise floor, which will help you to tune the scaling and offset parameters.